# Change the target version and other features when you upgrade your app

Tags: android, permissions

i'm developing an application and i will put it in the google play.

And i want to implement other features in a future upgrade.

This upgrade could change the target version of my app or for example have push-notifications.

What i want to know is if android gives the developers permission to change this features when i release an upgrade?

How does it work to new permissions etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will simply add that notification permission to your manifest, increment the buil version and build and upload it on google play, there will be no issue regarding this.

Extra permission will be shown to the user while they will be installing the app.

Tip: keep your signing key in a safe place. You will need this all the time while upgrading the app.

Comment: The user will be informed of any new permissions requested upon updating.